# Remover elemento luego de confirm AlertifyJS y JQuery

Tags: jquery

Cuando deseo eliminar el elemento del DOM con jquery luego de confirmar con alertifyJS me da el siguiente error: **Cannot read property 'parents' of undefined** creo que tiene que ver algo con el contexto `this`, he probado con otras cosas y todo va bien, pero al intentar borrar el elemento que disparó la acción no puedo.

He guardado en una variable el objeto que dispara la función para luego intentar llamarlo dentro pero no me resulta.

```
containerEventos.on('click','a.deleteAlimento',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var deleteTrigger         = $(this);
var nombreAlimentoBorrado = 
deleteTrigger.parents('.headAlimento').find('.nombreAlimento').text();
alertify.confirm('Borrar: ' + nombreAlimentoBorrado , function(e){
    if (e) {
        deleteTrigger.parents('.fullAlimento').remove();
    }
});
});
```

Algo curioso es que la función si reconoce el contexto al agregar lo siguiente:

```
.set('labels', {ok:'Alright!', cancel:'Naa!'})
```

Pero no me cambia los labels por los que deseo cambiar y me deja el siguiente error en consola:

**Uncaught TypeError: alertify.confirm(...).set is not a function**

```
containerEventos.on('click','a.deleteAlimento',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var deleteTrigger         = $(this);
var nombreAlimentoBorrado = 
deleteTrigger.parents('.headAlimento').find('.nombreAlimento').text();
alertify.confirm('Borrar: ' + nombreAlimentoBorrado , function(e){
    if (e) {
        deleteTrigger.parents('.fullAlimento').remove();
    }
}).set('labels', {ok:'Alright!', cancel:'Naa!'});
});
```